# Split max value between 3 independent trackbars

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This may be simple or it may be a long week and my mind just can't come up with the answer. Either way I'm stumped for an answer.

I have a Color array made up of ranges between 4 colors.

```
_sourceLookupColorRange = new Color[128];
```

Right now they are split evenly. 42 increments between color 1 and 2, 43 between 2 and 3 and 43 between 3 and 4.

```
Color set1 = Color.Green;
        Color set3 = Color.Yellow;
        Color set5 = Color.Orange;
        Color set6 = Color.Red;

        //find the interpolated values between the colors
        var res1 = ColorInterpolator.ReturnColorSet(42, set1, set3, 0);
        var res2 = ColorInterpolator.ReturnColorSet(43, set3, set5, 0);
        var res3 = ColorInterpolator.ReturnColorSet(43, set5, set6, 0);

        //copy the interpolated colors to the main source lookup array
        Array.Copy(res1, 0, _sourceLookupColorRange, 0, 42);
        Array.Copy(res2, 0, _sourceLookupColorRange, 42, 43);
        Array.Copy(res3, 0, _sourceLookupColorRange, 85, 43);
```

I would like to give the user the ability to drag sliders to set more 'weight' between color ranges. Perhaps 20 in the first two ranges and 68 in the third range. I would like to use 3 trackbars to allow easy use in the UI but need help in how to get it to work or if there is a sample of how it should be done.

Thanks

Comment: Search for **TrackBar** control, if you are using WinForms. There are plenty tutorials how to use it. You simply have to listen for scroll event and assign current value to variable.

Comment: https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c12101/Advanced-TrackBar-Slider-Control-with-MAC-Style-C.htm

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a ratio. Color range divided sum of values from 3 track bars gave me a ratio. I then multiplied each trackbar value by this ratio to give me the three scaled results I needed.